# Eliminar un registro de una tabla y esta se quite automaticamente en Angular

Tags: angular

quisera saber como puedo hacer cuando elimino un registro de una tabla esta automaticamente se quite de esa tabla, ya que cuanto elimino siempre debo de recargar la pagina para ya no ver el registro eliminado en la tabla.

Mi codigo ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ArtistaserviceService} from './../../services/artistaservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artista',
  templateUrl: './artista.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class ArtistaComponent implements OnInit{
  
  artistas:any[] = [];

  constructor(private artistaS:ArtistaserviceService) {
    
   }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.artistaS.getArtistas()
     .subscribe(data =>{
       this.artistas = data;
       console.log(this.artistas);
     })
  }

  borrarArtista(id:string){
    this.artistaS.borrarArtista(id)
    .subscribe(
      respuesta => {
        if(respuesta){
          console.log(respuesta);
          
        }
        else{
          delete this.artistas[id];
         

        }
      }
    )
    
  }

 
}
```

Mi HTML:

```
                <tr *ngFor="let art of artistas; let i = index">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>



                    <td>{{art.nombreartista}}</td>
                    <td>{{art.anonacimiento}}</td>
                    <td>{{art.descripcion1}}</td>
                    <td class="text-rigth w120">

                        <button [routerLink]="['/arts', art.idartista]" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
          Editar
          </button>

                        <button type="submit" (click)="borrarArtista(art.idartista)" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
          Eliminar
          </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

El operador `delete`no elimina elementos de un array, simplemente deja `undefined` en esa posición:

```js
let array=[1,2,3,4]

delete array[2];

console.log(array);
console.log(array.length);
```

Usa [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para eliminar:

```js
let array=[1,2,3,4];
array.splice(2,1); //desde la posición 2, eliminamos 1 elemento
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que el código que tienes en el `ngOnInit()` lo saques y lo escribas dentro de un método normal de la clase, así:

```
ngOnInit(){
   getArtistas();
}

getArtistas(){
   this.artistaS.getArtistas()
      .subscribe(data =>{
         this.artistas = data;
      console.log(this.artistas);
   })
}
```

haciendo esto, cuando ejecutes el método de **borrarArtista()** dentro del condicional que tienes pones el método **getArtistas()**, así:

```
if(respuesta){
   console.log(respuesta);
   getArtistas()     
}
```

haciendo lo anterior se te actualiza la información que estas mostrando

Answer (score 0):

Amigo con un .filter()  se puede hacer

```
borrarArtista(id:string){
    this.artistaS.borrarArtista(id)
    .subscribe(
      respuesta => {
        if(respuesta){
        this.artistas = this.artistas.filter( ar => ar.id != id)


          console.log(respuesta);
          
        }
        else{
          delete this.artistas[id];
         

        }
      }
    )
    
  }
```